# SSL error during cloud run external request on REST API - DOCKER

Tags: docker, api, rest, ssl, google-cloud-run

I have a API on cloud run developed using .NET 6. The API is working great, most routes are working as expected.

On my API I have some routes that needs to check on a external service making REST requests (mostly POST calls).

The problem is: when I take my API to cloud run, those routes don't work as expected. I receive an SSL ERROR during the request.

On my computer, coworkers computers (different ISP) and on a GCP VM the API work as expected.

The problem only occurs on cloud run.

```
{
  "success": false,
  "metaData": null,
  "dataHora": "2022-04-25T17:09:16.683683+00:00",
  "errorMetaData": {
    "stackTrace": null,
    "errorMessage": "Call failed. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception: POST https://************************/b1s/v1/Login",
    "innerError": {
      "stackTrace": null,
      "errorMessage": "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.",
      "innerError": {
        "stackTrace": null,
        "errorMessage": "Authentication failed, see inner exception.",
        "innerError": {
          "stackTrace": null,
          "errorMessage": "SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.",
          "innerError": {
            "stackTrace": null,
            "errorMessage": "error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol",
            "innerError": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

I think too is a problem in TLS compatibility because the API I'm trying to reach has a old TLS version.

Tried on my local machine using docker and received the same error - so it's not a cloud run issue, but some kinda of configuration in docker maybe?

Comment: I do not think this is a Cloud Run issue. Your problem is incompatible levels of TLS. For example, one side might require TLS v1.2 as the minimum but the other side only supports up to TLS v1.1. You either have a configuration problem or old libraries. Does your container work locally in Docker?  Edit your question with the Dockerfile and more information. Error messages by themselves are not useful.

Comment: If you run that app on your desktop (not with Docker) do you have the same problem? If you can reproduce the problem on your desktop then you can use WireShark to look at the protocol exchange to see the exact problem.

Comment: Tried running it on IIS Express and didn't have the same problem. but running locally with docker it happens.
BTW, I fixed it by changing the minimum version of TLS to 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the minimum version of TLS to 1.0 with the following code, before the ENTRYPOINT.

```
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
&& sed -i 's/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: These problems can be a callenge sometimes. Can you add to your answer the actual lines before and after changes from openssl.conf? This will make it easier for other to understand your answer.